# How can I multiply each column of a Tensor by all columns of an another using Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication

Let `a` and `b` be tensors defined as:

```
a = tf.constant([[1, 4],
                 [2, 5],
                 [3, 6]], tf.float32)

b = tf.constant([[10, 40],
                 [20, 50],
                 [30, 60]], tf.float32)
```

I am looking for a way to multiply each column of `a` by all columns of `b`, producing a result as below:

```
[[10,  40,  40, 160],
 [40, 100, 100, 250],
 [90, 180, 180, 360]]
```

I need an operation that can be performed over a tensor with an arbitrary number of columns (> 2).

I already developed a solution that can be used within a loop. You can checkout it [here](https://gist.github.com/lucasvenez/5adf645a30f97517c741c40da30c462c).

Thank you for you attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do I miss something? Why not just

```py
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant([[1, 4],
                 [2, 5],
                 [3, 6]], tf.float32)

b = tf.constant([[10, 40],
                 [20, 50],
                 [30, 60]], tf.float32)

h_b, w_a = a.shape.as_list()[:2]
w_b = a.shape.as_list()[1]

c = tf.einsum('ij,ik->ikj', a, b)
c = tf.reshape(c,[h_b, w_a * w_b])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(c))
```

edit: add `foo.shape.as_list()`

Comment: Thank you, Patwie!

Comment: Patwie, I improve my code using your tips. You can check it [here](https://gist.github.com/lucasvenez/5adf645a30f97517c741c40da30c462c). I cite you answer into the code. Thank you very much.

Comment: I would be nice, to accept [at least one of the answers] to mark this question as answered (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant([[1, 4],
                 [2, 5],
                 [3, 6]], tf.float32)

b = tf.constant([[10, 40],
                 [20, 50],
                 [30, 60]], tf.float32)

a_t = tf.transpose(a)
b_t = tf.transpose(b)

c = tf.transpose(tf.stack([a_t[0] * b_t[0],
                           a_t[0] * b_t[1],
                           a_t[1] * b_t[0],
                           a_t[1] * b_t[1]]))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(c))
```

For bigger matrices, however, you have to adjust the indexing.

Comment: Thank you, DocDriven! Your solution solved my doubt.